# Text scrolling up, but after closing the form. The text wont back on the start. vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I was able to scroll the text up, put a stop on it when it reached a certain location on Y.

However, when I was trying to load the credit form again. It will not be back on the start.

Here's the code I'm working on.

```
    Public Class creditsform
    Private Sub creditsform_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed

        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X, Label1.Location.Y = 304)  ' put back the label where it is.


    End Sub

    Private Sub creditsform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X, Label1.Location.Y - 5) ' scroll up the label up 
        If (Label1.Location.Y = -1506) Then ' closes the form if he reach the end of credit roll
            Timer1.Enabled = False ' disable the timer
            Me.Close() ' then close the form

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT: HERE IS THE FIRST LOAD AND THE SECOND LOAD OF THE FORM.
Also after the 2nd load, it doesn't execute the if else statement to close automatically the form.

[1ST LOAD & 2ND LOAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtKFz.png)

Here's where creditsform called.

```
Public Class EndGame


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim Red, Green, Blue As Integer
    Dim RandomNumGenerator As New Random
    Red = RandomNumGenerator.Next(0, 255)
    Green = RandomNumGenerator.Next(0, 255)
    Blue = RandomNumGenerator.Next(0, 255)
    Me.Label4.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue)
    Me.Label5.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click '' this button closes the form and shows the creditsform
    Me.Close()
    creditsform.ShowDialog()

End Sub
End class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly since it's not very clear what you are trying to do.

This is normal your using a class but not creating new instance of it so your variables don't reset. you should try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click '' this button closes the form and shows the creditsform
    Me.Close()
    Dim MyCredits As New creditsform
    MyCredits.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me knowledge regarding this. Yes it worked. I really do appreciate it!